# check if a json file already has the data i am overriding in python

Tags: python, json

I am currently making a python script that automates a task by sending an email after first parsing the data from a website then sending the message from that data using twilio.

But what I want is to first compare the data parsed with the already existing json file that I parsed previously and if it has same date or message then it should not send the message.

I have no idea how to do this I have tried to load the json file but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Here is my json file that I want to check:

```
{
    "date": "11/02/2016 11:42:57", 
    "message": "Dear students,\r\n\r\nAs informed in the class, this is to remind you Today special class from 6 to 6.50 pm at same venue SJT 126.\r\n\r\nregards\r\n\r\nR. Raghavan\r\nSITE", 
    "name": "RAGHAVAN R (SITE)", 
    "subject": "ITE308 - Distributed Systems - TH"
}
```

here is my code:

```
infoTable = tables[0].findAll('tr')
    name = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[0].text
    if (len(name) is 0):
        return None
    subject = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[1].text
    msg = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[2].text
    sent = infoTable[2].findAll('td')[3].text
textmyself.textmyself(msg)
    # Parsing the open hours of the faculties
    outputPath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'output')
    if os.path.isdir(outputPath) is False:
        os.makedirs(outputPath)
    result = {'name': name, 'subject': subject, 'message': msg, 'date': sent}
    with open('output/' + str(facultyID) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(result, outfile, indent=4)
    return result
```

**Update:** Here is what I tried and found working but json file should already be there if one is running script for the first time, so is my code correct?

```
with open('output/WS.json') as data_file:
        data = json.load(data_file)
    if data["date"] == sent:
        outputpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'output')
        if os.path.isdir(outputpath) is False:
         os.makedirs(outputpath)
        result = {'name': name, 'subject': subject, 'message': msg, 'date': sent}
        with open('output/' + str(facultyID) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
          json.dump(result, outfile, indent=4)
        return result
    else:
        outputpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'output')
        if os.path.isdir(outputpath) is False:
         os.makedirs(outputpath)
        result = {'name': name, 'subject': subject, 'message': msg, 'date': sent}
        with open('output/' + str(facultyID) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
          json.dump(result, outfile, indent=4)
        textmyself.textmyself(msg)
        return result
```

Comment: *so is my code correct?* Only you can answer that: does code achieve your desired results? And does code err out and if so where?

Comment: yeah! it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems such as trying to open the output file before you know it exists. Here's how you might do it.

As a side note, You calculate `outputPath` from the path of the executing script but use `"output"` in the current directory. Both have problems. The first doesn't work for installed scripts where you can't write the directory and may conflict with other users. The second way is dependent on where CWD happens to be. A third way is to base output on the user's home directory `os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'output')`.

```
output_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'output')
if not os.path.isdir(output_path):
    os.makedirs(output_path)
output_file = os.path.join(output_path, '{}.json'.format(facultyID))
if os.path.isfile(output_file):
    with open(output_file) as data_file:
        old = json.load(data_file)
    if old['date'] == date or old['message'] == msg:
        print('email already sent')
        return None
result = {'name': name, 'subject': subject, 'message': msg, 'date': sent}
with open(output_file, 'w') as data_file:
    json.dump(result, data_file, indent=4)
return result
```

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'output_file' referenced before assignment
I get this error?

Comment: Oops, my bad. It should be `output_file = os.path.join(output_path, '{}.json'.format(facultyID))`. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the old JSON file right away by using:

```
import json
with open('old_data.json') as f:
    old_message = json.load(f)
```

Then you can compare

```
if not old_message['date'] == sent:
    # send your mail etc.
```

Then bundle your data in another JSON and write the file back with the new message:

```
    new_message = {
        "date" : sent,
        ... }
    with open('old_data.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(new_message, f)
```

Putting together the pieces with what you already have, and also adding some error handling, should solve your issue.